# Pre-filtering joined elements in LINQ to Objects

Tags: c#, linq, filter

I have two collections, 'left' and 'right', having differing element types. The element types both have a string property 'paramNumber' which is not unique and the relationship via that is many to many. Now, there are two DateTime fields, 'left.date' and 'right.startDate'. For each selected 'left.date', I need to get the last element in 'right' where 'right.startDate' is smaller or equal (additionally to the join condition 'left.paramNumber' == 'right.paramNumber').

I wonder whether there is a direct way without full cross joins? I tried it with a sub query but got the problem with scoping of the 'lefty'' variable (see code).

I saw tutorials on the web doing a full cross-join first and then removing the undesired rows in the 'where' clause afterwards, but that is no option for us.

```
class left
{
    public string paramNumber;
    public DateTime date;
    public string leftyName;
}

class right
{
    public string paramNumber;
    public DateTime startDate;
    public string anotherString;
    public DateTime timeOfDay;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<left> lefts = new List<left>();
        List <right> rights = new List <right>();

        //lefty not visible in the where clause...
        //trying it with a second 'from right...' did not work because of
        //casting problems.
        var query =
            from left lefty in lefts
            join right righty in
               ((from right rightTmp in rights
                 where ((rightTmp.paramNumber == lefty.paramNumber) &&
                        (rightTmp.startDate <= lefty.date) &&
                        (rightTmp.anotherString == "N") )
                 select rightTmp
                ).ToList().Last())
            on lefty.paramNumber equals righty.paramNumber
            select new
            {
                myDate = lefty.date,
                myLeftyName = lefty.leftyName,
                myParamNumber = lefty.paramNumber,
                myTimeOfDay = righty.timeOfDay
            };
    }
}
```

[Edit]: **Solution (based on cechode's answer)**:

Below is the solution I currently use, based on cechode's answer.
The 'let' clause was the main missing piece, since it allows to reference l/lefty, too, not only r/rightTmp.

Finally, I did the full filtering to the one desired element within
'rights' directly in the first 'let' clause (by sorting ascending and using
Last(); of course cechode's descending/First() works, too) and spared the second one
with the 'toprightcheck' variable (I think cechode had good reasons for that null check, but I will try it with the shorter version):

```
var X = (from l in lefts
         let topright =
            (from r in rights
             where r.paramNumber == l.paramNumber && 
                   r.startDate <= l.date
             orderby r.startDate ascending
             select r).Last()        
         select new {
            lName = l.paramNumber,
            rname = topright.paramNumber,
            ldate = l.date,
            rdate = topright.startDate });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this do the trick for you?

```
var X = (from l in lefts
        let topright = (from r in rights where r.paramNumber == l.paramNumber && r.startDate < l.date orderby r.startDate descending select r)
        where topright!=null
        let toprightcheck = topright.First()
     select new { lName = l.paramNumber, rname = toprightcheck.paramNumber, ldate = l.date, rdate = toprightcheck.startDate });
```

Comment: Hi cechode,

so many thanks for your help, that worked! See my edits at the question for the variant I finally arrived at.